# Django Web App / Android WebView - How to send phone notification to Android device from Django

Tags: android, django, webview, push-notification, django-views

I finished creating my web app using Django and made the app responsive (using CSS media queries) and customized how it looks on mobile devices. I then created an android app. This app is just a WebView which points to the actual site.

Here is my models.py:

```
class Blog(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    blogPost = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class BlogComments(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    blog = models.ForeignKey(Blog)
    blogComment = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

And this is my view which handles BlogComments:

```
def createCommentView(request):
    if request.method=="POST":
        if 'blogID' in request.POST:
            blogID = request.POST['blogID']
            blogPost = Blog.objects.get(id=blogID)
            form = CommentForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                newBlogComment = BlogComments(user=request.user, blog=blogPost, blogComment=form.cleaned_data['blogComment'])
                newBlogComment.save()
```

At this point, I want to do something like this:

```
                send blogPost.user a push notification saying "request.user commented on your blog."
```

How would I do this? Again, the app is just a responsive Django App (created with Django, HTML, CSS, AJAX, JavaScript and Jquery). The Android App is just a basic WebView which points to the responsive website.

Edit:
If you are going to refer me to this:
https://django-gcm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/sending_messages.html

How exactly do I know what the users device name is in the line:
my_phone = get_device_model().objects.get(name='My phone')

Because on the previous page (https://django-gcm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/quickstart.html) it says to register a device, the URL is:

```
/gcm/v1/device/register/
```

so when I register a registered users device, how do I know what the device name is?

Comment: any proper solution yet ?

Comment: @PankajSharma No idea, I put this web view stuff on hold along time ago. I decided to make a Rest API using Django Rest Framework. I think using Android and sending requests to the API and displaying it is a good method.

Comment: Yo i was here looking for a different solution. How to put a local djangoWebsite into webview, i mean, i shouldn't need to post the website online. I know how to do it with simple html, css, js but where to point in dynamic website.